# Create Database on Runtime - Entity FrameWork Code-First

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have a project which saves its output results into an `SQLite` database.
in every run, the user should select the saving location which the program will create a database there and will save the result inside. so the database's name and location are dynamic.

How can I manage such a thing using `entity framework core code first`? I have create the models and the DbContext class, but I do not know how to create the database and tables on runtime and so on.

Comment: Modify the connection string appropriately and call EnsureCreated?

Comment: `Context.Database.EnsureCreated();` will create a database if not created

Comment: yeah I know but it gives this error: `You need to call SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider().  If you are using a bundle package, this is done by calling SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init().'`

Comment: Micrsofot docs: `Don't call EnsureCreated() before Migrate(). EnsureCreated() bypasses Migrations to create the schema, which causes Migrate() to fail`

Comment: @OkanKaradag so what should I do in my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, I should use `raw.SetProvider(new SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3());` in `OnConfiguring`:

```
public MyDataContext(string path, bool create = true)
{
    FilePath = path;
    if (create)
    {
        Database.EnsureDeleted();
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}

protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionbuilder)
{
    optionbuilder.UseSqlite($"Data Source={FilePath}");
    raw.SetProvider(new SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3());
}
```